# Open play store app from browser link

Tags: android, browser, google-play

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430336/redirect-users-to-itunes-app-store-or-google-play-store) I was able to create a functionality to redirect user to android or ios from a single link. However, on detection of Android I want to open the play store with my app shown. I tried the below link on redirect:

```
window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp";
```

but it opens the play store in the browser itself. I want to open the play store app, I am assuming that my app users will be having the play store app, so I do not want to check whether the play store app is installed or not. I also tried the market link as below

```
window.location.href = "market://details?id=com.myapp";
```

but this also does not work. Help appreciated.

Comment: you want to redirect from browser itself ? or from any click event ?

Comment: From the browser itself, no click event.

Comment: You are using webviewclient ?

Comment: No, I am sharing the link to my users via url.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I got it working by using the below url on redirect

```
window.location.href = "https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp";
```

When I visit this url from the browser of my mobile, it does not open the play store within browser but opens the play store app instead. This serves my purpose.

Comment: Can you explain why this link is working while the others return "Navigation blocked" error by the Browser. Can you specify a link to any documentation regarding this link.

Comment: Is there any similar way to launch appstore app on link click?

Comment: https://play.app.goo.gl/.well-known/assetlinks.json This is a dynamic link supported by Firebase and Play Service

Comment: Hello. When I try to  do this -

window.location.href = "https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp";

I get an Unsupported URI Scheme. 

It tries to load the webpage at intent://play.app.goo.... 
Any idea what I could do to fix it?

Comment: window.open() gave intent error, but window.location.href = works for me using `https://play.app...?link=https://play.google`

Comment: very good, but this only English language preview ;(

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by checking URL in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of your `WebViewClient`. See below

```
String market_url = "market://details?id=package_name";
String website_url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name";
```

onCreate ()

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");               // path to html
webview.setWebViewClient(new Callback());


private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals(website_url)) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(market_url));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name">App link</a>
```

This will always open your link in play store.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to do this could be

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
 if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
     window.location.href = 'http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en';
 }
 if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){
     window.location.href = 'http://itunes.apple.com/lb/app/truecaller-caller-id-number/id448142450?mt=8';
 }
});
```

Comment: From Chrome 40, `Navigation is blocked: market://details?id=****` is shown.