# How to open android app if app is installed or navigate user to play store from web application

Tags: javascript, android, html

I need to design a HTML page which contains a button. The button click event must handle the following functionality.

1. Open corresponding app if app is already installed.
2. Open the google play store link if app is not installed.

Is there a way where we can open app if it is already installed or take user to play store where he can install the app?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.href = "https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ticketnew.android.ui&hl=en";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xagdwqvj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a very clean Document on Deep linking. You should implement Deep linking on your Android app code so that we a web link is clicked it can open your app directly if it is installed on the same device.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: I agree, adding a intent filter will open the app. But what if the user has not installed the app. I need to check that and take user to play store. I am stuck with the second point specified in my question

Comment: Your myFunction() code should properly open the playstore. Try checking this link for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063523/open-play-store-app-from-browser-link

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to open the app as well open the app store. I need clarification on the logic to be build which decides whether we need to open the app or navigate to app store. I need the logic to check whether the respective app is installed or not.