# Facebook App Install Ads: Is it mandetory to have the SDK installed?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

We have developed a mobile app for both Android and iOS. We are planning to promote it through Facebook via **Facebook App Install Ads**. We don't want to track the number of installs or anything, because we can easily see these info in the app database.

However reading the following articles, we are very confused.

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/resources/faqs/

In the first link it sounds like we need to have the Facebook SDK installed. But in the second link, the first 2 FAQ says we don't need SDK if we are not planning to measure and track installs.

Out of this, which one is correct?

Our social media guy complains he can't create the App Install Ads in Facebook because FB says SDK is not installed in the app, but he himself admit he is not knowledgeable on this matter much.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a confusion between installing ads inside of your app, versus running ads on Facebook itself. **To run adds on Facebook you do not need an SDK installed in your app**, you just setup a Facebook Ads Account [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/redirect/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbusiness%2Fhelp%2Fredirect%2F&campaign_id=163681540489385&placement=%2Fbusiness%2Fgoals%2Fpromote-app) and submit your ad information, payment, etc. If I misunderstood your question please let me know.

Edit:

The easiest way to publish Facebook ads for your app is simply to link a website that routs to the correct App Store for the device -- the SDK setup is unnecessarily complex for what you're trying to accomplish. You can see how to
write a website to route the user: here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39749991/13296047

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, we need to run ads on Facebook. Specifically the ads which has the "Install App" button, where the client will be able to click and install our app.

Comment: @PeakGen Thanks for clarifying -- I updated my answer.

Comment: If we don't setup the SDK, can we show the "Install App" button ?

Comment: @SahanSamaranayaka Yes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the SDK to run these App Install button ads, but I've done some testing, and they don't seem to optimise very well. The ads run brilliantly for 24hrs, then fade quickly. I'm wondering if this is because the FB algorithm doesn't get a data feed for app installs, so doesn't know how to deliver the ad. Not 100% sure, this is still a theory I'm investigating...