# How to share different link depending on the platform of device that person who will be shared

Tags: flutter

I share link app's playstore link and appstore link according to platform.

```
 Platform.isIOS
                  ? Link(
                      mobileWebUrl: Uri.parse(
                          "https://apps.apple.com/~~~"),
                    )
                  : Link(
                      mobileWebUrl: Uri.parse(
                          "https://play.google.com/~~~"),
                    ),
```

But the problem is this platform means person who share, not person who will be shared.

So if user whose platform is android share link, even though friend's platform who get link is iOS, friend gets playstore link.

How to share different link depending on the platform of device that person who will be shared?

Comment: You can't, how should Flutter know the other person's os?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be within the scope of Flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** do this within Flutter itself.

`Platform.isIOS` is for the device *currently* running the app.

What you **can** do is:

1. On your website, detect their device and then redirect them to the correct Store link.
2. Use a service such as [linklyhq.com](https://linklyhq.com/support/app-redirects)

- See also [Redirect users to iTunes app store or google play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35430336/12349734)