# Open native app store from a single link?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

I am creating an app using PhoneGap for Android, iPhone and Windows Phone. I have to send a common URL in phone by SMS, so is it possible to open the native app store in the phone through a common link?

Like if someone have iPhone then after clicking on that link the app store will show that app to download.

Answer (score 4):

You could detect which OS the client is using and then proceed to load the correspondent URL. As Govind Singh Nagarkoti suggests in this post ( [redirect to appstore or google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464602/redirect-to-appstore-or-google-play) ) you could do something like this:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
         if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
             window.location.href = 'http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=PACKAGEURL';
     }
         if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){
             window.location.href = 'http://itunes.apple.com/lb/app/PACKAGEURL';
     }
    });
</script>
```