# How to redirect to mobile app?

Tags: android, ios

I've seen this before but can't find it.

How do you redirect a website visitor to download the website app from Appstore / Google play, if the visitor is visiting from a mobile browser / smartphone?

Kind regards

Comment: The answer is in this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464602/redirect-to-appstore-or-google-play/24465120#24465120

Answer (score 1):

You can use "deep links" e.g. https://firebase.google.com/features/dynamic-links/  (provide added benefit of bringing user to particular part of app....regardless whether they need to install app first).

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).